# AspectJ for logging order of which code is executed

Tags: java, aspectj, instrumentation, fuzzing

So I just finished my BSC Computer Science degree and my lecturer has given me a research project leading up to my honors course.

Basically it entailed understanding how American Fuzzy Lop worked for C based programs and finding a way to implement a similar Fuzzer tool for Java.

I'm currently looking for ways to do source-code and byte-code weaving/instrumentation.

The obvious tool would be ASM which would basically give me freedom to implement it in a variety of ways, but I've recently come across AspectJ which looks like it might be an easier alternative.

So my question is would it be possible to insert code via AspectJ so that I can output to a log file the order in which code was executed for methods and branching paths in loops.

An example in AFL is it uses a tuple system say A->B->C and the unique tuples would be AB and BC that I would log to a file indicating a new Tuple exists, where as A->B->D->E would only have the new tuples AD and DE which is a new path than the previous one, however the path A->B->C-> although a new sequence does not contain any new Tuples so it would not be a new path.

I'm not sure what documentation I could read that would give me an idea if this is possible.

One last question is AspectJ heavy-weight compared to ASM, since the Fuzzer tool would run the program several thousand times and I would like to achieve a fairly efficient method of instrumenting the code.

Answer (score 1):

Your question format is not very well-suited to StackOverflow, but I will try to answer briefly, but clearly:

- AspectJ can help you create a call tree, i.e. by implementing the right types of pointcuts and advices you can determine which method or constructor called which other method or constructor and so forth.
- AspectJ cannot tell you anything about intra-method code execution branches on the JVM byte code level such as if-else, switch-case, for-loops etc. If you need that, maybe ASM or even a professional debugging tool with an API or a good reporting interface would probably be better.

The answer for your particular case depends on what level of fuzzing you want to achieve. Ideally, it should be sufficient to cover the execution paths of a program by bombarding its public API with different kinds of input.

As for execution speed, AspectJ is quite good with a low overhead. But this statement only holds true as long as your aspect code itself does not impose a bottleneck by doing a lot of complicated stuff. So that is up to you.

Comment: (about the overhead) yes, especially if one does not abuse of AspectJ runtime mechanism such as cflow and so on.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. If AspectJ cannot tell me anything about branching paths, then I believe I'll have to stick to ASM, as the fuzzer needs to differentiate between different if-else statements and the amount of times a loop is executed.

Comment: Maybe you find a good open source code coverage tool which you can hook into in order to get the desired information. Those also work via instrumentation. If you can avoid to re-invent the wheel, maybe you want to check on that.